# finding maxima and minima of a quadratic equation

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

I'm dealing with a quadratic equation(with 2 independent variable) which looks like:
$$f(x,y) = 15.390x^2 - 0.001y^2 - 0.003xy - 69.985x + 0.263y + 58.740 $$ 
But I'm not being able to determine the maxima and minima for this equation.

So, a bit idea or reference regarding this issue would be nice.
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you familiar with using the [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Gradient)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the derivatives in terms of both x and y i.e.
$$\frac {\partial f} {\partial x} = 30.78x - 0.003y -69.985$$
$$\frac {\partial f} {\partial y} =-0.002y-0.003x+0.263$$

If you want to find the minimal/maximal points, then you should put the above 2 derivatives equal to $0$ and solve simultaneously.

If you would like to go further and determine whether that point is a minimum or a maximum, 
then create the Hessian which is just the matrix of 2nd order partial derivatives,
$$H(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}\frac {\partial ^2f} {\partial x^2} & \frac {\partial ^2f} {\partial x \partial y} \\ \frac {\partial ^2f} {\partial y \partial x} & \frac {\partial ^2f} {\partial y^2}\\\end{pmatrix}$$
Which is 
$$H(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} 30.78 & -0.003 \\ -0.003 & -0.002 \end{pmatrix}$$

Now since the Hessian is symmetric, then you have real eigenvalues. From here, you calculate the eigenvalues for this function. If both are positive then it is convex i.e. it is a minimum, if both are negative then it is concave i.e. it is a maximum.

Comment: As per this equation I'm getting one positive and another negative eigenvalue, i.e. 30.78 and -0.002.

Comment: That's fine. If one value is positive while the other is negative, that means it is a saddle point. But if you were to plot this in Matlab, you can see that it is only barely so. As can be seen [here](http://i.imgur.com/BiofbPX.png), the function looks overall convex, but I'm assuming that there are very small perturbations that don't make it completely convex. In fact, it can be evident from the 2nd eigenvalue which is very barely negative, that it is very close to being convex.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. And yes, I've plotted the whole dataset (and generated the quadratic function with coefficients) and then I was trying to determine if the minima lies in the saddle-point with some mathemetics. The plot is not completely convex rather is somewhat like hyperbolic paraboloid.

Answer (score 1):

First find the partial derivatives and put them equal to zero....

$$f_x(x,y) = 2(15.39)x -0.003y - 69.985 = 0$$
$$f_y(x,y) = -2(0.001)y -0.003x - 0.263 = 0$$

Solve these simultaneously to find the critical point $(x_c, y_c)$

Determine if critical point is maximum or minimum by using 
$$D(x_c,y_c) = f_{xx}(x_c,y_c)f_{yy}(x_c,y_c) - [f_{xy}(x_c,y_c)]^2$$

If $D > 0$ then we have Max/Min.

Distinguish between these as follows

- $f_{xx} < 0$ and  $f_{yy} < 0$ at $(x_c,y_c)$ point is Max
- $f_{xx} > 0$ and  $f_{yy} > 0$ at $(x_c,y_c)$ point is Min

Comment: but for this equation fxx = 2(15.39) and fyy = 2(-0.001), so how can I evaluate on (Xc,Yc).

Comment: Picture it and it'll be easier. If fxx and fyy are constants that means they are constant at all points including critical points. So the value of fxx on (Xc,Yc) is still 2(15.39) etc... Take a look at this link it will help you:http://www.analyzemath.com/calculus/multivariable/maxima_minima.h